# Spring Integration PostgresSubscribableChannel is not transactional

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-integration

With the following integration flow

```
IntegrationFlows.from(messageChannel)
                .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(rabbitTemplate)
                        .exchangeName("exchange")
                        .headersMappedLast(true)
                        .routingKeyFunction(message -> {
                            return "routing.key"
                        }))
                .get();
```

where **messageChannel** is a **PostgresSubscribableChannel**, if there is an exception in the handler (e.g. the broker is not available) the message is lost.

The message should "return" to the message store to be retried later.

By modifying the code **PostgresSubscribableChannel**, I can get the desired behavior; however I would like to know if this is a flow configuration problem on my side or if this an explicit design decision by spring integration for SubscribableChannels?

Answer (score 0):

Well, we never claimed that it is done transactionally. But that's OK to raise a GH issue with more details and see what we can do on the matter.

The current behavior is to poll for a message in the `PgConnection` thread, but then hand it off to an `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` of the `UnicastingDispatcher` in that `PostgresSubscribableChannel`:

```
public void notifyUpdate() {
    Message<?> message;
    while ((message = this.jdbcChannelMessageStore.pollMessageFromGroup(this.groupId)) != null) {
        this.dispatcher.dispatch(message);
    }
}
```

Looking forward for your modifications though!

Comment: I will push my changes to a GitHub so that we can discuss if my approach can be a basis for a PR

Comment: Yes, PR is also OK: we treat them as equal to issues.

Comment: Opened issue [PostgresSubscribableChannel is not transactional](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/8582)